# Find the start and end of a string and write into CSV in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have huge txt file with multiple lines in it.

I want to create an array which stores the start of a line with "PROCEDURE" and ends with "END;".

Then i need to search within the array [Start with "PROCEDURE" & Ends with "END;"] whether I have any lines with "EXCEPTION" as string.

If i don't find the string "EXCEPTION" within the array I have to write a message to a file the "Exception is not found", if found then write message as "Exception is found"

File Format for reference

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
CLEAR;
EXIT

PROCEDURE FP_XXXXXX

IS

---------
---------
EXCEPTION

---------
---------
ENDS;

FUNCTION FF_

AS

--------
--------
```

---

Regards,
Marc

Comment: Will the `"exception"` strings be found on separate lines, or can they be on the same line as the start/end strings?

Comment: Hi Mathias, Thanks for you response. Exception string will between the Start and End String.

Comment: Please update your example and show us what it would ook like if the word "Exception" is present.

Comment: Thanks Theo for your response. 

Just an example of the file will look like, there will be many occurrences like below in the file. Wherever we find we need the exception we need to write "Exception found" in CSV if its not found then need to write "Exception not found" in CSV

PROCEDURE (Start String)

-----
-----
EXCEPTION
-----
-----
END; (End String)

Answer (score 1):

Let's break the problem down into:

1. Read the lines from the file on disk
2. Go through them until `PROCEDURE` is found
3. For each subsequent line:

   - If line starts with `END`, return/quit
   - If not, check if it contains the string we're looking for

---

Translated to PowerShell, we might come up with something like this:

```
$started = $false
$exceptionFound = $false

# 1. Read the lines from the file
foreach($line in Get-Content .\path\to\file) {
  if(-not $started){
    # look for `PROCEDURE`
    $started = $line -clike 'PROCEDURE*'
    continue
  }

  # look for END
  if($line -clike 'END;*'){
    # we're done here
    break
  }

  # otherwise, look for the string
  $exceptionFound = $line -like '*exception*'
  if($exceptionFound){
    break
  }
}

# $exceptionFound will hold the answer at this point
```

Comment: Hi Mathias R. Jessen, Thanks for your suggestion

Exception returns as "FALSE" even thought the "EXCEPTION" string was found. Please guide

Comment: @Marc Remove the `;` I erroneously added after `PROCEDURE`

Comment: Mathias, Just tried to print the values(Write-Host)... Initially for the very first time the $started value comes as True

    $started = $actpath.trim() -clike 'PROCEDURE*'
    Write-Host $started    ----> Returns True

  $exceptionFound = $line -like 'EXCEPTION'
  Write-Host $exceptionFound ---> Returns only False

Comment: `$actpath`? Replace with `$line`, and remember the wildcards around `EXCEPTION` (unless that's the _exact_ string)

Comment: Mathias, 

Start of the program they are doing the below, so using $actpath as the file contents are in it.

foreach($line in Get-Content $txtSource) {
$actpath =$line

EXCEPTION is the exact string we are searching for between the PROCEDURE and END; strings

Comment: That works, but it loads the entire file into memory up front. Given that the question states "I have huge txt file", I suggest using `switch -File` instead.