# Store lines in an array - Start to End using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have huge txt file with multiple lines in it.

I want to create an array which stores the start of a line with "PROCEDURE" and ends with "END;".

Then i need to search within the array [Start with "PROCEDURE" & Ends with "END;"] whether I have any lines with "EXCEPTION" as string.

If i don't find the string "EXCEPTION" within the array I have to write a message to a file the "Exception is not found", if found then write message as "Exception is found"

Sample Input:

```
PROCEDURE FP_XXXXXX

IS

BEGIN

{CODE}

EXCEPTION

{Exception_block}

END;
```

Sample Output in the CSV:

```
Exception is found
```

Regards,

Marc

Comment: Please don't ask [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62794339/find-the-start-and-end-of-a-string-and-write-into-csv-in-powershell) multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
$procedure = $false # Tracks when inside PROCEDURE block
$array = switch -regex -casesensitive -file file.txt {
    '^PROCEDURE' { $_; $procedure = $true }
    '^END;' {$_; $procedure = $false }
    default { if ($procedure) { $_ } }
}

if ($array -cmatch 'EXCEPTION') {
    'Exception is found'
}else {
    'Exception is not found'
}
```

This should be faster than using `Get-Content`.

`-regex` enables regex matching in your switch conditions. You can remove the `-Casesensitive` switch if case does not matter in the matching.

Comment: It's not clear, but your answer should be fine either way (unless a procedure is named `EXCEPTION`, which seems unlikely).